# SQL Server temporal table doesn't keep delete history for update and delete within a transaction

Tags: sql-server, temporal

I have a SQL Server temporal table "person" with a record like this:

```
name      | modified_by
-------------------------
John      | 1
```

If I execute the following sql statements

```
update person set modified_by = 2 where name = 'John'
delete from person where name = 'John'
```

I see two records in the history table with modified_by = 1 and 2 respectively.

If I execute the two statements within a transaction

```
begin transaction
  update person set modified_by = 2 where name = 'John'
  delete from person where name = 'John'
commit transaction
```

I only see one record in the history table with modified_by = 1

Is it the expected behavior? Why?

Comment: I know this is late, but just encountered the same issue myself. You don't say how you're querying the history table but if you query it directly you should see the version with modified_by = 2. However it is not returned by ```select * from person for system_time all```, perhaps because its valid_from and valid_to timestamps are the same.

Comment: This seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54562240/capture-sysendtime-on-sql-server-temporal-table-delete

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is expected.

All statements within a transaction are either performed completely or not at all. There's no intermediate step.

In your example the update statement is a waste of resources since the related row will be deleted anyway.

Your fist statement however, without the transaction, will result in three consistens state of the table: before the first statement, after the update and after the delete.

Comment: The purpose of the two statements is to keep the history of who delete the record. So the first update statement makes sure that I know the person (modified_by = 2) is the one who delete the record.

Comment: The second statement re waste of resources is not correct. The update *is* reflected in the history table as is required by OPs use case. However it has an empty validity period (the update is superseded by the delete in the same instant), which I presume is why it is not returned by a ```for system_time all``` query.